# Auto insert custom post type title

Tags: custom-post-types

Is it possible to change the custom post type title based on another selected field? Basically i'm trying to do this:

[image]

Comment: it depends whether you want to change it in the database (on save), upon setting the custom field, or just filter the title upon retrieval..?

Comment: @majick i want to change it in db when setting the custom field

Comment: hmmm what is the ID of the select element there? and are you using the option value or the option text for the title?